# Cumalative column while other column does not change in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```html
unit      start    stop
A      0.0    8.15
A      9.18   11.98
A     13.07   13.80
B     13.82   15.00
B     16.46   17.58
A     17.62   17.98
B     18.01   19.99
B     20.10   25.11
```

How do I create 4 columns that do the following:

**consecutive_unit_count** (two columns, one for each unit)

This column keeps a running tally of the amount of consecutive units that occur before the unit changes. It resets to 0 after a unit change.

**consecutive_unit_time** (two columns, one for each unit)

This column keeps a running tally of the amount of time between the start and stop for each row until the unit changes. It also resets to 0 after a unit change.

The resulting df should look as below:

```html
unit  start stop  unitA_tally  unitA_time  unitB_tally  unitB_time
A      0.0    8.15    0          8.15         0             0
A      9.18   11.98   1         10.95         0             0
A     13.07   13.80   2         11.68         0             0
B     13.82   15.00   0           0           0           1.18           
B     16.46   17.58   0           0           1           2.30
A     17.62   17.98   0          0.36         0             0
B     18.01   19.99   0           0           0           1.98
B     20.10   25.11   0           0           1           6.99
```

Comment: Are corrects your columns unitA_time and unitB_time?

Comment: I calculated them by hand to build this desired output, but yes they should be correct.

Comment: I don't understand how you obtain it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are actually looking for `tally=cumcount, time=cumsum`. So here's what I would do:

```
# these are the blocks
s = df['unit'].ne(df['unit'].shift()).cumsum()

# time for each row
times = df['stop'] - df['start']

# compute the new df 
new_df = (times.groupby(s)
            .agg(tally='cumcount', time='cumsum')  
            .assign(unit=df['unit'])               
            .pivot(columns='unit', 
                   values=['tally', 'time'])
            .fillna(0)
         )

# rename the columns
new_df.columns = [f'unit{y}_{x}' for x,y in new_df.columns]

# concat
pd.concat((df, new_df), axis=1)
```

Output:

```
  unit  start   stop  unitA_tally  unitB_tally  unitA_time  unitB_time
0    A   0.00   8.15          0.0          0.0        8.15        0.00
1    A   9.18  11.98          1.0          0.0       10.95        0.00
2    A  13.07  13.80          2.0          0.0       11.68        0.00
3    B  13.82  15.00          0.0          0.0        0.00        1.18
4    B  16.46  17.58          0.0          1.0        0.00        2.30
5    A  17.62  17.98          0.0          0.0        0.36        0.00
6    B  18.01  19.99          0.0          0.0        0.00        1.98
7    B  20.10  25.11          0.0          1.0        0.00        6.99
```